# I can't setId to a dynamic a Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I can't setId to a dynamic a Spinner!?

What I am trying to do is add 1 Spinner for every TableRow, depending on the amount of rows in a database (I am NOT trying to just show the database). The spinner's id needs to be set based on the number in the database.

```
final String mArray[] = { "1", "2", "3" };

do{
    int db_number = c.getInt(getColumnIndex("number"));
    int db_type = c.getInt(getColumnIndex("type"));

Spinner sp_type = new Spinner(this);
sp_type.setId(db_number + 10000);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = newArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    mArray);
sp_type.setAdapter(adapter);
if (db_type == 1) {
    sp_type.setSelection(0);
} else if (db_type == 2) {
    sp_type.setSelection(1);
} else {
    sp_type.setSelection(2);
}
tr.addView(sp_type);
}while(c.moveToNext());
```

This crashes the app. However, if I remove the line "sp_type.setId(db_number + 10000);" I do not get an error.

Here's the logCat:

```
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edjr/com.edjr.Settings_EditDb}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState(CompoundButton.java:339)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:6278)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:6257)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1486)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:844)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.TabActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(TabActivity.java:58)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:816)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1625)
06-05 01:21:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: normally you don't set an Id in run time, if you need to reference your view later, use `setTag()` instead.

Comment: Works... why dont you setId in runtime?

Comment: From your stack trace, the error is not setId but from `android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState`, which comes from `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState`. Problem is your ID is not set in the onCreate event and when the Activity try to resume, it cannot find that particular Id to load, that raise above exception. Moreover, you can never know whether the Id you provide is not used by others in your context.